# Error while processing analysis Server, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: sql-server, ssas

When trying to process the database from SQL Server Management the following error occurs and the whole analysis won't process.

The error is correct the file is missing from the directory, is there any way I can run it without using the file named. Or how to fix.

Error Message:

> The following error occurred while opening the file '\D:\SSAS_Data\AvantBI_Analytics_LIVE.0.db\Plot Sale Details (10).tbl\486.prt\32974.Plot Sale Details (10).RowNumber 2662979B 1795 4F74 8F37 6A1BA8059B61 (11).0.idfmeta': The system cannot find the file specified. .
> (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: As for the error, Well `\\?\D:\ ` is certainly *not* a valid UNC path.

Comment: Though you've updated the question with the text, your image *did* have `\\?\D:\ ` as the path, not the `\D:\SASS...` you have (which too is not a valid UNC path, as it would either be `D:\SSAS...` or `\\ServerName\d\SSAS...`). Either way, your path is invalid and hence the error.

Comment: @Larnu The file path has not been changed recently, the `\\?` is a prefix used specify an extended-length path

Comment: Unprocess the database, then do a full reprocess. Pay special attention to any errors that might occur *other* than the file not found error.

Comment: @JeroenMostert is 100% right on the best fix